# Why doesn't my best score value load after game closes and launches again?

Tags: iphone, swift, sprite-kit

My best score value works perfectly fine if the game keeps running, but it won't load the best score if the game closed and was to launch again. It goes back to zero every time it the launches again.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
import SpriteKit

class EM: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var bestScoreText = SKSpriteNode()

let bestScoreCategory: UInt32 = 1 << 4

var bestScoreLabelNode = SKLabelNode()
var bestScore = NSInteger()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    var bestScore = 0

    var bestScoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    bestScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("bestScore")

  }



func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {


    if (score > bestScore) {

        bestScore = score

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setInteger(bestScore, forKey: "bestScore")
        defaults.synchronize()

    }

    } else {
......
}
```

AppDelegate.Swift:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let defaultValues = ["bestScore" : 0]
defaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use an optional value, the score is supposed to be never nil

The usual way to treat `user defaults` is to register the key value pairs to have reliable default values.

---

So in AppDelegate – as soon as possible – write

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let defaultValues = ["bestScore" : 0]
defaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)
```

It doesn't matter that this code is called at every application launch.
If any of the keys exist in the `user defaults` database, the default value is ignored.

---

Declare the variable `bestScore` as non-optional `Int` with a starting value of 0.
As `Int` is the default type, the type can be omitted.

```
var bestScore = 0
```

---

To read the high score from `user defaults` use

```
bestScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("bestScore")
```

Checking for `nil` is not needed as we know we have a default non-optional value of 0

---

To write the high score to `user defaults` use

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setInteger(bestScore, forKey: "bestScore")
defaults.synchronize()
```

Comment: Ok. This helps. I'm getting a declaration error for 'defaults' in App Delegate. I have updated on how my App Delegate looks like. I think I'm messing up something.

Comment: The code must be placed in a method. Put it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or better, implement `awakeFromNib`

Comment: I did everything like you said, but it still doesn't work. I have updated my code with how you said.

Comment: So, it worked when I took the variable part off off the var bestScore.